# object oriented-ness, extensability and modularity for simple program

Tags: oop, modularity

How efficiently we can apply object oriented-ness, extensability and modularity for simple program? If it is application I can identify Entities and relations between them. When it comes to simple program I am not able to do this.

Please help me in achieving object  oriented-ness, extensability and modularity in the Berlin clock program in the link.

http://technologyconversations.com/2014/02/25/java-8-tutorial-through-katas-berlin-clock-easy/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: One of the things I experienced is that keeping it small and simple helps you achieve many other clean coding goals. It helps better practices - avoiding duplication, better methods, APIs, better design, etc "emerge". So while programming anything - module, class, methods, loops, I always ask myself 'can I make it small?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would tackle the problem

1. **object oriented-ness**
   First of all find out all the entities involved in your problem. Then intepret them as classes. In this case for example the clock is based on different Lights and their inter communication to display actual time.

So I would consider Light as an abstract class and would also inherit different other lights (E.g. RedLight, YelloLight etc) from this abstract Light class and extend them.

2. **Extensability**

Always use interfaces rather than directly accessing the classes. In this way you could replace or extend your classes

3. **Modularity**

Have your Model (Classes), Business Logic, UI Logic etc separated in different class libraries (or separate projects).

Hope this simple explanation helped.